# php, mysql data transform

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

First, sorry for my English. I'm a beginner in these things, and i have a simple question.   I'm storing data in mysql. One column contains data in the format (for example): a,b,c,d or a,c,d, or a,d ...
Now, after query i want to change this values:

```
 a = apple, b=blueberry, c=cat, d=dog ...
```

for example if column contains

```
 a,d,
```

i want to change and print apple, dog...

One more time, sorry for my English. Please ask if anone didn't get the question.

thanks.

Comment: Do you have such pre-defined array ?

Comment: You can use a "dictionary" for such purpose. SOmething with a key-value structure. The dictionary can be contained in the database or statically implemented inside your scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$map = array('a' => 'apple', 'b'=>'blueberry', 'c'=>'cat', 'd'=>'dog');

$column = 'a,d'; //your data here

$result = strtr($column, $map);
```

---

update:

```
$arr = explode(',', $result);
$links = array();
foreach($arr as $item) { 
$links[] = $commonURLpart . $item; 
}
```

Comment: It is almost perfect for me. One more thing missing. I want to create separated links from $result.

Comment: `$arr = explode(',', $result); foreach($arr as $item) { $links[] = $commonURLpart . $item; }`

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the power of the `REPLACE()` string function:
Usage:

```
REPLACE(str,from_str,to_str)
```

Returns the string `str` with all occurrences of the string `from_str`
replaced by the string `to_str`. Also `REPLACE()` performs a **case-sensitive**
match when searching for `from_str`.

URL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html

For example: `SELECT REPLACE('www.mysql.com', 'w', 'Ww');` will output `WwWwWw.mysql.com`

Update: The method above changes the content during **runtime** at MySQL level.
If this is not relevant, you can change the content of your output during **runtime** with simple PHP string replace magic, by using `str_replace()` PHP function. This way you will store the original data in database intact and you will output the desired substituted strings.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create another table like:

```
+--------+-----------+
| letter | word      |
+--------+-----------+
| a      | apple     |
| b      | blueberry |
| c      | cat       |
| d      | dog       |
+--------+-----------+
```

And then do a join query similar as this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `table1` as t1
JOIN
    `table2` as t2
ON
    t1.letter = t2.word
```

This will automatically convert your letter into desired words.

*PS: I could make the query more understandable, if you could post an example of your original table data.*

Comment: Your solution is same good for me, but not I am not fully understand. The column store data in this format "  a,b,c,d "

Comment: How does the original table look like?

Answer (score 0):

you can use if condition to do so, you need your custom values e.g

```
<?PHP
---prev code

$db_col     = strtolower($row['col']);
if($db_col=='a'){
   echo 'Apple';
}elseif($db_col=='b'){
    echo 'Blueberry'    ;
so on ........  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have the query result in an associative array...

so, first thing is "cycling" the array:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($replace_with_name_of_associative_array))
{
   if (strtolower($row['repalace_with_column_name'])=='a'){ //strtolower just in case you have "A" and "a", "B" and "b",...
   echo 'Apple';
   }elseif(strtolower($row['repalace_with_column_name'])=='b'){
     echo 'Blueberry';
     }
   //and so on...

}
```